# trying to make overlapping rectangles on canvas grid

Tags: random, grid, processing, overlap

I´m trying to make a grid with overlapping squares that change between black and white. So far I could do the grid responsive to the canvas, also assign a random color, but the overlapping part doesnt quite work out. I tried adding a black stroke to the black squares but somehow there are very small squares appearing. Any ideas? Here´s my code:

```
void setup() {  
  size(900, 900);
}



void draw() {
  fill(255);
  noStroke();
  int divW=width/6;
  int horS=divW/5*2;
  int divH=height/6;
  int verS=divH/5*2;
  
  
  for (int p = 0; p < width; p = p+divH-verS) {
    for (int q = 0; q < height; q = q+divW-verS) {
      push();
      
      int col = int(random(100));
      if (col <= 65) {
        fill(0);
      }
       
      rect(q, p, divW, divH);
      pop();
      
  
}
  }

if (frameCount == 10) {
    exit();
    }
   
    saveFrame("output/2grid65_o###.png");

}
```

[IMG of what I was getting without the stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLaxA.png)

[IMG of what I´m getting with the stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4i7.png)

[IMG of what I want (see the overlap between squares?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuZry.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the white squares are overlapping the strokes on the black squares, which gives you those little bits sticking out from behind.

Since your background is white, a simple solution would be to not draw the white squares (just let the background show through). Then you should be able to use your stroke method to have them overlap.

```java
int col = int(random(100));
if (col <= 65) {
    // only draw the square if it's black
    fill(0);
    rect(q, p, divW, divH);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. The problem is that I am not filling the white rectangles. Only the black. At the beginning the only thing that´s white is the background. I need the stroke as well because that is how I achieve the overlap of the black squares

Comment: You are filling the white squares. `fill(255);` at the beginning of your draw function sets the fill to white. You change it to black inside the if statement, but then draw a rect outside of the if statement. So if a black square isn't chosen, you draw a white square. If you move the `rect` call into the if statement you'll only draw the black ones.